# Cannot setup Apache Arrow v11 on Mac

Tags: java, apache-arrow

I am getting all sorts of weird errors when setting up Apache Arrow v11 on my Macbook.

I'm following steps from [Apache Arrow documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/developers/java/building.html#system-setup).

Step 1 : Clone the repo - Success

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/arrow.git
cd arrow
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Step 2 : Building Java Modules - Success

```
cd arrow/java
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-18.0.2.1.jdk/Contents/Home
java --version
mvn clean install
```

Step 3 : To build only the JNI C Data Interface library - **Fail**

```
$ mvn generate-resources -Pgenerate-libs-cdata-all-os -N
```

**Error Dump**

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.045 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-16T23:00:50+10:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "generate-libs-cdata-all-os" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/Users/apple/Downloads/arrow). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

Then I ignored the Step 3 and moved to IntelliJ IDEA to setup my environment.

Now I get even more errors.

```
Cannot find symbol class Unsafe
```

```
/Users/apple/Downloads/arrow/java/memory/memory-core/src/main/java/org/apache/arrow/memory/util/MemoryUtil.java:40:23
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Unsafe
  location: class org.apache.arrow.memory.util.MemoryUtil
```

```
package sun.misc does not exist
```

```
/Users/apple/Downloads/arrow/java/memory/memory-core/src/main/java/org/apache/arrow/memory/util/MemoryUtil.java:28:16
java: package sun.misc does not exist
```

Below is my environment setup

```
(base) apple@appurunoMBP arrow % java --version
java 18.0.2.1 2022-08-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2.1+1-1)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2.1+1-1, mixed mode, sharing)
Maven home: /Users/apple/apache-maven-3.8.8
Java version: 18.0.2.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-18.0.2.1.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_AU, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "13.2", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
Processor : 2.9 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i9
macOS : 13.2 (22D49)
```

Comment: Hi, Could you try to run `mvn generate-resources -Pgenerate-libs-cdata-all-os -N` inside of `arrow/java` instead of `arrow` directory please.

Comment: I tried then I get below error
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec (cdata-cmake) on project arrow-java-root: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

Comment: Could you try this command to share error logs please: `mvn clean generate-resources -Pgenerate-libs-cdata-all-os -N -X`

Comment: [INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec (cdata-cmake) on project arrow-java-root: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec (cdata-cmake) on project arrow-java-root: Command execution failed.

Comment: at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.

Comment: at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)

Comment: at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)

Comment: It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /Users/apple/Downloads/arrow/java-jni/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-ub6fyf
    
    Run Build Command(s):/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -E env VERBOSE=1 /usr/bin/make -f Makefile cmTC_36a02/fast && xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (project)

Comment: Please, let's start again. Arrow Java contains = Java Core Modules + Java JNI Modules. What are you trying to do? Compile the core + jni modules (Do you need to compile locally the JNI modules also?) or Open the project inside a IDE?. In case of trying to open the modules inside a IDE take a look at https://arrow.apache.org/docs/developers/java/building.html#ide-configuration

Comment: Compiled Java Core modules locally and then loaded the maven project to Eclipse and build again (clean install) then added those external JARs to an empty Java project and try to import the modules but all in red marked gives me error.